# Searching original data on backspace

Tags: javascript

I’ve got the following JavaScript script.  The data is pulled from a database and populated into a table.  Then, as the user types in the search box, it filters through data in the table on keyup and only displays relevant rows.  **That works great, until the person types wrong and uses backspace.**

Right now, its only searching what is left until the search box is empty.  Once the search box goes empty, it finally pulls up all the original data again.

**What I need, is for it to filter through all the data on every keyup.  So if the user types in something wrong and they use backspace, it will bring up relevant data from the original data.  Not just data from the point where they messed up.**

---

### Example

```
FH-54
FH25
FH325
FH-25
```

If I type in FH-, it will filter the results down to `FH-54` and `FH-25`.  But, if I didn’t mean to type the `-`, and I take the dash out via backspace, it still only leaves the `FH-54` and `FH-25` as results.  **The rest don’t show back up until the search box is completely empty.**

---

Below is the code I’ve been using

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(".searchbox").on('keyup', function () {
                if ($(this).val() != '') {
                    search(this);
                }
                else {
                    $(".data").show();
                    $.each($(".searchbox"), function () {
                        if ($(this).val() != '') {
                            $(this).keyup();
                        }
                    });
                }
            });

            function search(ele) {
                var val = $(ele).val().toLowerCase() || '';
                if (val == '')
                    return;

                var dataclass = $(ele).attr('data-class');
                var SearchInText = '';
                $.each($(".data:visible"), function () {
                    SearchInText = $(this).find("td." + dataclass).text().toLowerCase();
                    if (SearchInText.indexOf(val) == -1)
                        $(this).hide();
                });
            }
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code. I think It is what you want!

```js
$('#Search').on('keyup', function(e) {
  $("#noData").remove();
  var value = $(this).val();
  value = value.replace(/\\/g, '');
  var patt = new RegExp(value, "i");
  var sw = 0;
  var counter = 0;
  $('#Data').find('tr').each(function() {
    counter++;
    if (!($(this).find('td').text().search(patt) >= 0)) {
      $(this).not('#header').hide();
      sw++;
    } else if (($(this).find('td').text().search(patt) >= 0)) {
      $(this).show();
    }
  });
  if (sw == counter) {
    $("#Data").append(`<tr id="noData">
                  <td colspan="2">No data</td>
                </tr>`);
  } else {
    $("#noData").remove();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><input id="Search" type="text" placeholder="Search" /></div>
<table id="Data">
  <thead>
    <tr id="header">
      <th>Col 1</th>
      <th>Col 2</th>
      <th>Col 3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tr>
    <td>FH-54</td>
    <td>BH-54</td>
    <td>CH-54</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>FH25</td>
    <td>LH-54</td>
    <td>KH-54</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>FH325</td>
    <td>MH-54</td>
    <td>NH-54</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>FH-25</td>
    <td>LH-54</td>
    <td>YH-54</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: How would I add additional column searches?  On other pages, I created the ability to search different columns for diff values using the same script.  Will this do the same?

Comment: Basically, creating multiple “search boxes” and adding different “data-class”’s to each one

Comment: You can do multi-columns search also with one search box! Which one is better for you? @UnitedProDesign

Comment: Give me time, I change the code for multi-columns search! @UnitedProDesign

Comment: Try it now. @UnitedProDesign

Comment: This works perfectly!  Thanks!  How well does this perform with large data sets?

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a forEach only in the visible elements:

```
            $.each($(".data:visible"), function () {
                SearchInText = $(this).find("td." + dataclass).text().toLowerCase();
                if (SearchInText.indexOf(val) == -1)
                    $(this).hide();
            });
```

So, I suppose that as you hide already some, the forEach still iterates over the same set.

This means that if you only have `FH-*` data visible, and you erase the dash, the `.data:visible` is still only `FH-*`.

When you erase everything, `$(this).val() != ''` this becomes false and then this executes:

```
                $(".data").show();
                $.each($(".searchbox"), function () {
                    if ($(this).val() != '') {
                        $(this).keyup();
                    }
                });
```

If the dataset isn't huge, I recommend you to add this:

```
 $(".data").show();
```

Before doing the `search(this);`.

Comment: Right now its upward to about 300 products.

Comment: That's big but not huge. If it becomes to be more than a thousand, you might encounter a problem, but you shouldn't face it using jQuery if you seek for performance.

Comment: Changing that does not help.  I took out :visible and it still does the same thing.

Comment: Could you then please provide a running example?

Comment: How?  Everything Is pulled from a database

Comment: With fake data. Stackoverflow encourages MVCE: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Trying to get it to work.  Not working on jsfiddle... https://jsfiddle.net/m44xomfw/2/

Comment: Updated the answer.